# Can we check in polynomial time if the language of a DFA is closed against Kleene star?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, regular-languages, time-complexity

I was wondering if there is a polynomial time algorithm to test whether a DFA recognizes a star closed language ( which is if $A=A^*$). I think that yes, but I do not have an idea to do it.

Comment: Polynomial in which parameter?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, probably in the size of the DFA's description. At least that would be the usual measure for these kinds of problems.

Comment: See also a different but related question on cstheory: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4254/a-special-class-of-languages-circular-languages-is-it-known.

Comment: big-O @J.-E.Pin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your DFA $A = (Q,q_0,F,\delta)$ is minimal, here is one approach:

$L(A) = L(A)^*$ iff $q_0$ is accepting, and adding $\epsilon$-transitions from each accepting state $q$ to $q_0$ does not change the language; the latter is true iff $L(A)\subseteq L(A_q)$ for each $q\in F$, where $A_q = (Q,q,F,\delta)$.

In order to check whether this holds, you can compute the product $A\times A$ and check whether the subset $F\times(Q\setminus F)$ is unreachable from $\{q_0\}\times F$, which you can do in polynomial time. In some more detail:

The product automaton has the form $A\times A = (Q\times Q, (q_0,q_0), F\times F, \delta')$, where

- the set of states $Q\times Q$ consists of all pairs $(q_1,q_2)$ with $q_1,q_2\in Q$;
- the initial state is the pair $(q_0,q_0)$ (though we won't be needing it for our purposes);
- the accepting states are all pairs $(q_1,q_2)$ where both $q_1,q_2$ are accepting in $A$;
- the transition function $\delta'$ applies the original transition function to both components of a pair, i.e. $\delta'((q_1,q_2),a) = (\delta(q_1,a),\delta(q_2,a))$.

In order to check whether $L(A)\subseteq L(A_q)$ for some $q\in F$, we start from the pair $(q_0,q)$; there should be no word $w$ such that $\delta(q_0,w)\in F$ and $\delta(q,w)\notin F$, which is equivalent to the set $F\times(Q\setminus F)$ being unreachable from $(q_0,q)$ in $A\times A$.

For example, consider the language given by the regular expression $(a + ab + ba)^*$ mentioned earlier by J-E. Pin. It is accepted by the automaton $A=(Q,q_0,F,\delta)$, where

- $Q=\{q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3\}$,
- $F=\{q_0,q_1\}$,
- $\delta = \{(q_0,a,q_1),(q_1,a,q_1),(q_2,a,q_0),(q_3,a,q_3),(q_0,b,q_2),(q_1,b,q_0),(q_2,b,q_3),(q_3,b,q_3)\}$.

The only pair we have to check is $(q_0,q_1)$; exploring the states we can reach from it, we get:

- $\delta'((q_0,q_1),a) = (q_1,q_1)$ - note that both components are the same; since $A$ is deterministic, this will be also be the case for all states reachable from here, in particular we will never reach any $(q,r)$ with $q\in F$ and $r\notin F$. We therefore don't need to explore this branch any further.
- $\delta'((q_0,q_1),b) = (q_2,q_0)$. Fine because $q_2\notin F$.
- $\delta'((q_2,q_0),a) = (q_0,q_1)$. Back to where we started.
- $\delta'((q_2,q_0),b) = (q_3,q_2)$. Not only is $q_3\notin F$, but it is a trap state, i.e. all states we can reach from here are of the form $(q_3,q)$ and therefore not in $F\times(Q\setminus F)$.

Since we cannot reach $F\times (Q\setminus F)$ from $(q_0,q_1)$, we now know $L(A)\subseteq L(A_q)$ and therefore $L(A) = L(A)^*$.

Comment: Is there another way for checking than computing product of A * A? and check whether the subset F×(Q∖F) is unreachable from {q0}×F?

Comment: There might be - but how different would a solution have to be to count as "another way"? Many "different" approaches would be essentially the same thing in disguise.

Comment: Ok, why you compute the product A×A? do you mean Aq? and what is the subset F×(Q∖F) ?I did not understand.

Comment: Just to be sure - is it the notation (cartesian product $S\times T$, set difference $S\setminus T,\dots$) you are unfamiliar with?

Comment: Doesn't adding epsilon-transitions make it NFA?

Comment: @Macrophage The automaton that you get by adding those $\epsilon$ transitions to $A$ (let's call it $A_\epsilon$) is an NFA, but all I use it for is to formulate a condition (that $L(A) = L(A_\epsilon)$ in addition to $q_0\in F$). $A$ itself is still deterministic (as are the variations $A_q$ and the product automaton)

Comment: Thanks, now I get it, that's really clever! Also, instead of your product construction and the reachability argument, can we instead take the intersection of $A,A_\epsilon$ (which still involves a product, but is certainly poly-time computable) and then check equivalence of the intersection and $A$ (which is also poly-time computable) ? Just wondering if this alternative strategy also works.

Comment: @Macrophage A problem with that approach is that by construction, $L(A_\epsilon)\supseteq L(A)$, since $A_\epsilon$ has all the states and transitions of $A$ plus the extra $\epsilon$-transitions. The language of the intersection will therefore always be equal to $L(A)$.

Comment: @KlausDraeger thanks for your quick reply! I'm sorry there was a typo, I didn't really mean $A_\epsilon$ but actually $A_q$ as described in your original answer. And I'd like to check the equivalence of intersection for every q, wondered if that works.

Comment: @Macrophage That would work, yes. It would essentially amount to the same approach as the product construction given above - Each of those intersections would have state set $Q\times Q$ and differ only in the starting state ($(q_0,q)$ for the intersection with $A_q$). The goal for each intersection would be to check that no word is accepted by $A$ but not by $A_q$, i.e. that $F\times (Q\setminus F)$ is unreachable.

Comment: @KlausDraeger Thanks, now I see these are indeed the same approach worded differently!